# Java get pow with BigInteger

Tags: java, math, biginteger

Find the last ten digits of the series, 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 1000^1000

I'm using Java.. I think I can modpow function for this question. (BigInteger) Here is my Java code but it isnt work. How can I do that?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger a;
    BigInteger b = null;
    BigInteger c = new BigInteger("10000000000");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        a = new BigInteger("" + i);
        b.add(a.modPow(a, c));
    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

I get the error of NullPointerException..  Sorry my english, thanks.

Comment: This can be solved without using BigInteger.

Comment: `BigInteger b = null;` So you are getting NullPointerException at `b.add(`.

Comment: How can be solve without using BigInteger? 
----
I write that line like 
"BigInteger b=new  BigInteger("0");" However, it doesnt work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger num = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            num = num.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i).pow(i));
        }
        BigInteger res = num.mod(new BigInteger("10000000000"));
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

output :

```
9110846700
```

More efficient solution taken from http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-48-last-ten-digits/ as biginteger gets very slow on very large numbers

```
import java.io.InputStream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long result = 0;
        long modulo = 10000000000L;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            long temp = i;
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                temp *= i;
                temp %= modulo;
            }

            result += temp;
            result %= modulo;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

output :

```
9110846700
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BigInteger b = null;
```

therefore, in the first iteration, when you do `b.add(a.modPow(a, c));`, `b` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two basic errors, first you never initialized `b` - that could be

```
BigInteger b = BigInteger.ZERO;
```

Then you need to assign the result of the `b.add(a.modPow(a, c));` to `b` (since BigInteger add doesn't modify in-place). That is,

```
b = b.add(a.modPow(a, c));
```

When I make those two changes I get the output

```
4629110846701
```

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not a zero value. Initialize your variable with `0` like this

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("0");
```

Even if, as peter.petrov said, this problem could be solved with one more simple solution without using big integers